# Understanding of LDR and STR?

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm using ARMSim which I guess its a ARM simulator and I have this demo program. It basically reads a text file and prints the integers from the text file (only the first line).

```
Start:
@Open file for input.
LDR R0, =InputFileName
MOV R1, #0
SWI SWI_Open
BCS FileError

@Save file handle to memory.
LDR R1, =InputFileHandle
STR R0, [R1]

@Read integers.
LDR R0, =InputFileHandle
LDR R0, [R0]
SWI SWI_RdInt

@Print to ARMSIM console.
MOV R1, R0
MOV R0, #Stdout
SWI SWI_PrInt

BAL End

FileError:
MOV R0, #Stdout
LDR R1, =FileErrorMess
SWI SWI_PrStr
BAL Quit

End:
SWI SWI_Exit

.data
.align
InputFileHandle: .skip 4
InputFileName: .asciz "integers.txt"
FileErrorMess: .asciz "Can't open file."
```

It runs fine but I don't really understand how the LDR or STR instructions work. Especially the ones that look like LDR R0, [R0] or STR R0, [R1]. Can anyone clear things up on how these work?

Answer (score 7):

The `LDR` and `STR` instructions use post-indexed addressing to update their address registers.

- `STR` instructions store a word in memory.
- `LDR` instructions load a word from memory.

[Read more](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABFGBDD.html)

Comment: So looking at this LDR R0, [R0]. Is this code saying that [R0] is some sort of address that will be loaded into R0? Does this address hold some sort of value?

Comment: The address holding the constant remains valid regardless of where the linker places the ELF section containing the LDR instruction

Comment: LDR R0,[R0] loads R0 with a value from memory using R0 as the address of that memory. STR R0,[R1] stores the value in R0 into memory using R1 as the address of that memory. For another example, LDR R0,[R2,#4] would load R0 with the value from memory using (R2+4) as the address.

Comment: [arm reference for ldr, str](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/Bcfihdhj.html "arm reference for ldr, str")

Comment: In case it's not clear: LDR R0,[R1,#4] uses R1+4 as the address and loads R0. LDR R0,[R1,#4]! uses R1+4 as the address, loads R0, and adds 4 to R1, or it could add 4 to R1 then use the updated R1 as the address and load R0. LDR R0,[R1],#4 uses R1 as the address and afterwards adds 4 to R1.

Comment: @rcgldr So for example lets say that R3 has a value of 10. (MOV R3, #10) If I do this (LDR R0, [R3]) does this do anything?

Comment: @rcgldr And also from your explanations, I know that a register is like box that holds items, but if you use LDR, the register has some sort of memory address where it holds the item? So I can shift this address by using LDR R0, [R3, #4] or whatever number (#) I want?

Comment: | MOV R3,#0x10 | LDR R0,[R3] | => loads R0 with the value at memory address 0x10. If this was followed by | LDR R0,[R3,#4] | then it loads R0 with the value at memory address 0x14. To use shift, the third parameter is different. I think the syntax is | LDR R0,[R3,LSL #2] | which would load R0 from memory address 0x40.