# The reset of page table

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, arm, page-tables

In arch/arm/kernel/head.S,I found following code

```
__create_page_tables:
pgtbl   r4, r8              
    mov r0, r4
    mov r3, #0
    add r6, r0, #PG_DIR_SIZE
1:  str r3, [r0]， #4
    str r3, [r0]， #4
    str r3, [r0]， #4
    str r3, [r0]， #4
    teq r0, r6
    bne 1b
```

I got that this the operation that resets the page table, but why `str r3,[r0], #4` executes four times?why it can't be

```
      add r6,r0,#PG_DIR_SIZE
1:    str r3, [r0]， #4
      teq r0, r6
      bne 1b
```

I guess it is due to the length of memory unit.

Comment: Note this is a post-increment addressing mode, so `r0` is incremented by 4 after each store.  The overall effect is to store zero to four consecutive words in memory, a total of 16 bytes.  It looks like just an unrolled loop to zero out a region of size `PG_DIR_SIZE`.

Comment: Is `strd` not baseline?  With two zeroed registers, it could be storing 8 bytes per instruction.  Or apparently still just one zeroed reg works: https://godbolt.org/z/fddac9Pbb but GCC only uses it for ARMv6t2 or higher.  And does use `str` not `stmia`, so at least compilers think 4-byte stores make sense if they can't use 8-byte.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding of LDR and STR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401542/understanding-of-ldr-and-str) Or alternatively: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947320/arm-32-bit-str-instruction,

Comment: Loop unrolling is a choice for performance.  It could be done with just one `str` in the loop.